# Is it possible to connect Microsoft keyboard and Logitech mouse to a single receiver?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, mouse

I'm considering buying [Logitech Wireless Marathon Mouse M705](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034XRDUA) and [Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Wireless Keyboard for Business](https://www.adorama.com/mis5kv00001.html?utm_source=rflaid913051). Each comes with it's own dongle. I wonder if can connect two devices to a single receiver(by MS or Logitech).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally not, as they will be built on incompatible systems. If they wanted to be compatible, they would be bluetooth, and not need a dongle at all.